# ActionEvent confusion

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, actionlistener

I'm very new to Java and I'm confused about the `ActionEvent` class.

I was under the impression that to use a class you had to create a new object for example:

```
SomeClass aClass = new SomeClass();
```

But in this piece of code:

```
private class theHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
       Event.getSource() 
      // etc...
    }
}
```

How come you don't need to:

```
ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent();
```

Event become an instance of the `ActionEvent` class without having explicitly tell it.
I'm sorry of this is a dumb question, I'm teaching my self Java, and this is thoroughly confusing to me.

Comment: I guess `Event.getSource()` should be `event.getSource()`. The code in your original post (before the edit) didn't even compile because of incorrect usage of capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

ActionEvent **is** created somewhere, but it's just not being created explicitly by you. Rather, it's being created in the JButton's code (actually the code is in the AbstractButton class, a parent class for JButton) for notifying all ActionListeners that listener are attached to it. You can view the source file to see the details if you desire.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `implements` in Java, what you are doing is using an [**interface**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). Interfaces require certain methods to be implemented in your code and offer a way to ensure new classes that implement a certain interface have methods that can be called.

Thus, in your example:

```
private class theHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
       event.getSource() 
      // etc...
    }
}
```

The `ActionListener` interface is being implemented by `theHandler` and therefore the method, `actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)` is required to be implemented by your class. There is no explicit `ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent();` being created here because the `ActionEvent` is actually being passed through as a parameter to `actionPerformed` and is otherwise being created somewhere else.

Specifically for your example, you can also do the following instead of using the `implements` keyword on your class:

```
public class theHandler {
    public theHandler() {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // do some stuff here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really quite simple, there is a thing called static methods. These are methods you can use from a class without making objects of them.

Like the Math class and all it's functions fx. a static method could look like this:

```
public class HiClass {
    public static String sayHi() {
      return "Hi!";
    }
}
```

You would then use it in some context like this:

```
System.out.println( HiClass.sayHi() );
```

This would print out the string the method returns in your console.

You might ask "why wouldnt I just make all my methods in my classes static then?" there are many reasons, main one I can think of is that when you program you always try to restrcit responsibilities to classes that makes sense, so that the code is more manageable and easier to alter as the program grows.

This is not specific to the context your mentioning though, but it seemed to me your real question is how you can use methods without creating an object?

Hope it answers your question?